# allocating an array of a paramterized derived type with a deferred length

Tags: arrays, oop, fortran, gfortran

I am unable to successfully allocate an array of a derived type that has an array of deferred length. I found a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58976091/fortran-allocatable-array-of-allocatable-derived-type) with an answer that seemed promising but I am unable to get it working.

```
program test

  implicit none
  integer :: n_x, n_y, n_z

  type soils_type(n)
    integer, len :: n
    real, dimension(n) :: var1
  end type

  type cell_type(n)
    integer, len :: n
    type(soils_type(n)) :: soils
  end type

  type model_type
    type(cell_type(:)), allocatable :: modelgrid(:,:)
  end type

  type(model_type) :: m
  n_x = 2
  n_y = 3
  n_z = 3
  allocate(cell_type(n_z) :: m%modelgrid(n_x,n_y))

end program
```

gfortran (gcc version 13.1.0) gives the following error when attempting to compile the code :

```
  25 |   allocate(cell_type(n_z) :: m%modelgrid(n_x,n_y))
     |                             1
Error: Type of entity at (1) is type incompatible with typespec'
```

gfortran (gcc version 11.2.0) gives the following error when attempting to compile:

```
main.f95:25:29:

   25 |   allocate(cell_type(n_z) :: m%modelgrid(n_x,n_y))
      |                             1
Error: Type of entity at (1) is type incompatible with typespec

[Compilation failed with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Why do you have `integer, kind :: n_z` in `cell_type` when the type parameter for `soils_type` is a length-type parameter? Kind-type parameters cannot be deferred, so `type(cell_type(:))` isn't allowed. Equally,  If `cell_type` has a kind-type parameter then that must be a constant in `cell_type(n_z)` in your allocation. You surely mean `integer, len :: n_z` in `cell_type`.

Comment: @francescalus Thanks for having a look. I implemented your suggested change but no receive a different compiler error.

Comment: That looks like a compiler bug to me. Can you try with another compiler or GCC version?

Comment: @francescalus Using an earlier version of gcc seemed to break it further. I updated the post accordingly.

Comment: Those complaints with GCC 11 suggest that you're asking it to compile with strict F95 conformance. Are you using `-std=f2018` to be sure?

Comment: @francescalus Correct. I fixed that but am now getting the same error as before.

Comment: Both code versions look fine to me (but that's only on casual glance, as my wetware compiler needs a break), so I can suggest only trying a different compiler.

Comment: It failed for me with gfortran. I tried with the NAG compiler (version 7.0) and got ```Fatal Error: test.f90: Nested parameterised derived types with length type parameters are not available```. But I managed to get it to compile with the ifort compiler from the Intel oneAPI compiler suite. Maybe give it a year or two for other compilers to catch up.

Comment: Thank you both for you looking at this. This is disappointing but I'm glad to know why it doesn't work. I was trying to avoid making var1 an allocatable array and then allocating after having allocated modelgrid because, according to my understanding, var1 would then not be stored in memory with the rest of the type's variables (soils_type has other scalar variables that I excluded from the example code). If the above code were to work, I was hoping to access var1 as model_type%modelgrid%soils%var1. However, because it will not work, I believe I need to loop over XY and every modelgrid cell.